# Multiple actions after selecting item from ListView KOTLIN

Tags: listview, position, selected

Im working on la ListView and I want it to assign some datas into a webViews and EditTexts after selecting an item from the list, I imagined something like this:

```
        list.setOnItemClickListener { adapterView, view, i, l ->
        when(i) {
            0 -> webView.loadUrl("https://web1") 
            0 -> phone.text ="phonenumber1"
            0 -> webView2.loadUrl("http:web2")

            1 -> webView.loadUrl("https://web3")
            1 -> telefono.text ="phonenumber1"
            1 -> webView2.loadUrl("https://web4")

            2 -> webView.loadUrl("https://web5")
            2 -> telefono.text ="phonenumber1"
            2 -> webView2.loadUrl("https://web6")

            3 -> webView.loadUrl("https://web7")
            3 -> telefono.text ="phonenumber1"
            3 -> webView2.loadUrl("https://web8")

            4 -> webView.loadUrl("https://web9")
            4 -> telefono.text ="phonenumber1"
            4 -> webView2.loadUrl("https://web10")

        }
```

However only the first line of each selected position is working properly.

thank you in advance for your support.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
when (i) {
   0 -> {
       webView.loadUrl("https://web1")
       phone.text ="phonenumber1"
       webView2.loadUrl("http:web2"  
   }
  1 ->  { ... }
  2 ->  { ... }
  3 ->  { ... }
  4 ->  { ... }
}
```

Blocks allow you to have multiple statements in when branches...hope it helps! Have a nice day...